# Shorhand in javascript for codes with same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, shorthand

I have various codes like this :

```
            $(function() {

            $('#slider1').carouFredSel({
                auto: false,
                infinite:false,                 
                circular:false,
                prev:'#prev1',
                next:'#next1',
                pagination:"#pager1",
                mousewheel:true,
                swipe: {
                    onMouse: true,
                    onTouch: true
                }
            });

        $('#slider2').carouFredSel({
                auto: false,
                infinite:false,                 
                circular:false,
                prev:'#prev2',
                next:'#next2',
                pagination:"#pager2",
                mousewheel:true,
                swipe: {
                    onMouse: true,
                    onTouch: true
                }
            });         
        });
```

```
      window.addEvent('domready', function(){
```

var container = document.id('container'),
    queuedElems = [];

    var sorter = new Fx.Sort($$('#container .sort'), {
    duration: '1000',
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Back.easeInOut,
    mode: 'vertical',
    onComplete: function(){
        displayDOM();
      }
   });

    displayDOM();

    document.id('swap').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    var elems = container.getChildren();
    sorter.swap(elems[0], elems[elems.length - 1]);
  });



    window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    var container = document.id('container2'),
    queuedElems = [];

    var sorter = new Fx.Sort($$('#container2 .sort'), {
    duration: '1000',
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Back.easeInOut,
    mode: 'vertical',
    onComplete: function(){
        displayDOM();
      }
  });

    displayDOM();

    document.id('swap2').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    var elems = container.getChildren();
    sorter.swap(elems[0], elems[elems.length - 1]);
  });

I'd like them to be written the 'shorthand' way since everytime the settings in each code are the same, only the ID names change (ID1, ID2...). I have no clue how to do this in javascript (only in css). The only thing I know is that you need the 'var' tag.

Anyone with a little knowledge can do it easily i guess. I tried many combinations myself but always failed. An example would be nice.  Is it difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You could do 2 things:
Select multiple elements via ID using `,` or assign a common class (`.slider`)

```
 $('#slider1, #slider2').carouFredSel({
            auto: false,
            infinite:false,                 
            circular:false,
            prev:'#prev1',
            next:'#next1',
            pagination:"#pager1",
            mousewheel:true,
            swipe: {
                onMouse: true,
                onTouch: true
            }
        });
```

or store the settings into a variable

```
 var mySettings =  {
            auto: false,
            infinite:false,                 
            circular:false,
            prev:'#prev1',
            next:'#next1',
            pagination:"#pager1",
            mousewheel:true,
            swipe: {
                onMouse: true,
                onTouch: true
            }
        };
    $('#slider1').carouFredSel(mySettings);

    $('#slider2').carouFredSel(mySettings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a common class to all those elements, and initialize the plugin once for all of them at the same time -- `$('.slider')` instead of `$('#slider1')` for instance.